# Windows Server 2012 - SSL Cypher Suite Order Not Long Enough

Tags: security, ssl, windows-server-2012

I want to re-order the cypher suites on our new Windows Server 2012 box to help mitigate the BEAST vulnerability for our clients. I went to `Local Group Policy => Computer Configuration => Administrative Templates => Network => SSL Configuration Settings`, opened **SSL Cypher Suite Order**, enabled it, and copied the values from the **SSL Cypher Suites** textbox.

I pasted them into notepad, re-ordered them, then copied+pasted them back into the **SSL Cypher Suites** textbox. However, the box isn't long enough to hold them all, despite the fact that the length didn't change. I would have to drop the last 3 cyphers (`SSL_CK_DES_192_EDE3_CBC_WITH_MD5,TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA`) in order for it to fit.

Should I just drop them? Other ideas?